# ¿Como sustraer una fragmento de texto de un string, con ciertas condiciones?

Tags: java

Lo que pasa es que necesito sustraer un fragmento de un texto, pero desde que comience con "x palabra" hasta "x palabra"

Ejemplo:

```java
String texto = "Hola necesito ayuda con un problema, si es que son amables de ayudarme, gracias";
```

De ese string necesito extraer desde "necesito ayuda" hasta "ayudarme".

Pero necesito que **NO** sea asi:

```java
String sustra = texto.substring(5,70);
```

Repito, que el resultado sea de la palabra que quiero que empiece hasta la que quiero que finalice.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Bueno, primero que todo se que para empezar a buscar por una palabra usé el .indexOf(). Pero no se como hacerlo para la palabra final que deseo en que termine la frase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con `split()` para dividir la frase completa por palabras en un `array` y un método que reciba como parámetro la palabra inicial, la palabra final y el `array` de palabras:

Tenemos el texto declarado e inicializado:

```java
String texto = "Hola necesito ayuda con un problema, si es que son amables de ayudarme, gracias";
```

Procedemos a dividirla, palabra por palabra, de acuerdo a los espacios:

```java
String[] frase = texto.split(" ");
```

Lo anterior guarda un `array` de palabras llamado `frase`.

Una vez hecho lo anterior, se realiza el método que se encargue de devolver la frase de acuerdo a la palabra inicial y final pasada como parámetro:

```java
public static String devuelveFrase(String palInicial, String palFinal, String[] fraseFragmentada){
        boolean inicioEncontrado = false; 
        boolean finalEncontrado = false;
        String fraseCompleta = "";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < fraseFragmentada.length; i++){
           //para encontrar la palabra inicial
           if(palInicial.equals(fraseFragmentada[i])){
               inicioEncontrado = true;
           }
           //si inicial es true guarda los datos hasta que final sea true
           if(inicioEncontrado){
               if(finalEncontrado == false){
                   fraseCompleta += " "+fraseFragmentada[i]; 
               }
               
           }
           //Comprueba que se encontró final
           if(palFinal.equals(fraseFragmentada[i])){
               finalEncontrado = true;
               
           }
        }
        return fraseCompleta;
}
```

**Explicación**

1. Primero, el método recibe 3 parámetros:

   `palabraInicial` = Corresponde a un `String`, la palabra por la cual la frase debe de comenzar

   `palabraFinal` = Corresponde a un `String`, la última palabra que debe de contener la frase.

   `fraseFragmentada` =  Corresponde a un `String[]` (`array` de `String`), el cual contiene la frase fragmentada palabra por palabra.
2. Se tienen dos variables `boolean` (`inicioEncontrado` y `finalEncontrado`), las cuales son incializadas en `false`.
3. Luego 1 variable `String`

   `fraseCompleta` = lo que retorna el método.
4. Con un `for` recorrí todo el `array`, si es que la palabra inicial fue encontrada `inicialEncontrada` cambia a `true` y comienza a guardar la frase correspondiente, hasta que `finalEncontrada` sea `true`

> **Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

He puesto la palabra final con `,`, ya que falta una validación.

---

## EDIT

Puedes de igual manera como lo has estado intentando hasta ahora con  `.indexOf()` de esta manera se reduce un montón el código y es mucho más legible y comprensible:

```java
public static String devuelveFrase2(String palabraInicio, String palabraFinal, String texto){
        String fraseCompleta = "";
        int indexPrimera = texto.indexOf(palabraInicio);
        int indexUltima = texto.indexOf(palabraFinal) + palabraFinal.length();
        
        fraseCompleta = texto.substring(indexPrimera, indexUltima);
            
        return fraseCompleta;
}
```

En este caso no se tiene que realizar un `split()` simplemente se pasa el texto y las dos palabras, la de inicio y la del final. Además del texto completo.

La frase se rellena con el texto recortado, desde el `index` de la palabra del inicio y hasta el `index` de la palabra de al final, más su largo, para que esta última pueda ser añadida a la frase de igual manera.

> El resultado es el mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que bien!!! Te lo agradezco de corazón, me ha resultado muy útil. La verdad me salvaste ya que no podía encontrar ninguna solución.

Comment: He añadido un nuevo método que hace lo mismo y está mucho más reducido, mis disculpas el primero lo hice media dormida ): el segundo es más fácil de comprender :)

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre algo así:

```
String texto = "Hola necesito ayuda con un problema, si es que son amables de ayudarme, gracias";
int desde = 3, hasta = 6;

String[] splitted = texto.split(" ");
StringBuilder aux = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = desde; i <= hasta; i++) {
    aux.append(splitted[i - 1] + " ");
}
String res = aux.toString();

System.out.println(res); // ayuda con un problema,
```

Esto suponiendo que cada palabra siempre estará separada por un espacio (si puede haber más espacios o saltos de línea una expresión regular viene bien). Con algunas mejoras y validaciones creo que es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido correctamente, lo que queires es seleccionar una parte de la frase en base a expresiones regulares variables, en tu caso, palabras.

Puedes hacerlo haciendo uso de las clases **Pattern** y **Matcher**, que te permitirán compilar una expresión regular y buscar el patrón dentro de un texto. En función de las posiciones en las que localice los patrones que le indiques, podras extraer una parte u otra de la frase, siempre dinamicamente.

Te añado un codigo de ejemplo:

```
String texto = "Hola necesito ayuda con un problema, si es que son amables de ayudarme, gracias";
String pattern1 = "necesito ayuda", pattern2 = "ayudarme";

Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(text);
matcher1.find();

int start = matcher1.end();

Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(pattern2);
Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(text);
matcher2.find();

int end = matcher2.start();

System.out.println(texto.substring(start, end));
```